# How to publish an NPM TypeScript package with nested folders

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a TypeScript project which is pointless to break down into smaller packages, nevertheless I have some sub-folders in the code for logical organisation purposes.

During development I had nicely namespaced imports in the application using the module, because the TypeScript files were local:

```
import { MyClass } from "./MyModule";
import { MyNestedClass } from "./MyModule/SomeFolder";
```

But now I want it in NPM the only way I can find to package and publish results in imports like this:

```
import { MyClass, MyNestedClass } from "MyModule";
```

How can I configure my `package.json` etc. such that I can maintain the namespaces I have in my source code to achieve something like this from a package in node_modules:

```
import { MyClass } from "MyModule";
import { MyNestedClass } from "MyModule/SomFolder";
```

Having organisationally scoped projects isn't the answer and doesn't neatly solve my needs, although I am using them.

Comment: I would think this would already be working ... what file are you using for typings and what does it look like?

Comment: Well with NPM you specify a main js file, from here you export all the public API members. With just one main js file, the exports are always rooted to the module name. I hope that makes sense, please correct anything I've misunderstood as I'm very new to publishing node packages.

Comment: @joshcomley did you find any workaround?

Comment: @Emech sadly not just yet :(